# Anybody have a link to Plex debian package pre v1

Tags: plex

I found many issues with the new plex, and I see there is a major revision change and I'd like to revert. From what I read, they deleted the repo and all I can find is old windows version of Plex. Anybody happen to have a deb file pre v1?

Comment: Unfortunately, checking my servers cache is a no-go as I deleted the old VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found this, thought I'd share

```
wget "https://downloads.plex.tv/plex-media-server/0.9.16.3.1840-cece46d/plexmediaserver_0.9.16.3.1840-cece46d_amd64.deb"
```

Comment: Not sure what they did, but its back like it used to be, 5 minutes and a new Plex v0.9 server is running as it should. The downside of simple installs is, I had no idea what to troubleshoot with new version...